# In Firefox, container doesn't get children width using display inline-block

Tags: css, firefox, display

I have the following structure:

```css
#out {
  padding-bottom: 40%;
  height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

#in {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.image {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="out">
  <div id="in">
    <div class="container"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/sbyPaAsl.jpg" alt="" class="image"></div>
    <div class="container"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/sbyPaAsl.jpg" alt="" class="image"></div>
    <div class="container"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/sbyPaAsl.jpg" alt="" class="image"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Basically, a container with `height: 0;` and a `width` and `padding-bottom` set in percentage (the padding is supposed to be the exact value to fit all the images, in the real scenario); inside it a container which inherits the parent size with `position: absolute;`; and 3 divs which should float one next to the other getting its width from each children image using `display: inline-block;` (I tried also `float: left;` with no result).

Chrome, Safari and Opera display images in the same way: `.container` has the width of the children image. But in Firefox (OSX) `.container` width is `0`.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there some way to get this working the same way in Firefox?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oqafhuc1/1/).

Comment: Is there a question here? Are you asking if you're doing something wrong or if it's an issue with Firefox?

Comment: Thanks @bugfroggy, I'll edit the question. Well, I want to get it working in Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure *why* it was causing the issue, but I found a fix. Simply updating your `display` from `inline-block` to just `inline` worked for me:

```css
#out {
  padding-bottom: 40%;
  height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

#in {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  display: inline;
}

.image {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="out">
  <div id="in">
    <div class="container"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/sbyPaAsl.jpg" alt="" class="image"></div>
    <div class="container"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/sbyPaAsl.jpg" alt="" class="image"></div>
    <div class="container"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/sbyPaAsl.jpg" alt="" class="image"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Tested on Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. It works for this case, however now the problem is moved to the height of `.container`. But it solves the issue I had. Thanks again.